# Disable and enable event handler in Razor

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have partial View, that is used in all other views in my website. In one page, i need to disable the click effect of a link and then after some actions enable it again. I am able to disable it using the following code

```
 $("#Link").off();
```

But I am not able to enable it again. I tried with $("#Link").on(); but it doesn't work.
Since I new to web development, I am having a hard time figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use jQuery's `off` method. It removes all event handlers from that element (and throws them away). Instead, disable that element:

```
$("#Link").prop('disabled', true);
```

and to enable it:

```
$("#Link").prop('disabled', false);
```

events don't fire for disabled elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean flag to determine whether the element is enabled or not:

```
var linkEnabled = true;

// Return false if link is not enabled
// (It will continue normal execution if it returns true)
$('#Link').on('click', function() {
    return linkEnabled;
});

// Example: disable link on click of another element, then re-enable it after some actions
$(yourElement).on('click', function() {
    linkEnabled = false; // disable link
    // Do some stuff here
    linkEnabled = true; re-enable link
});
```